# Shopify How to add meta fields to product in liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to figure out How to add meta fields to product in liquid

I have a product that has a list of meta fields (scents) how do I add the selected meta field to the product. I don’t want the scents to be variants.

Example on a candle product page user selects strawberry scent how does this get added to cart as candle strawberry scent?

I added meta-field list in settings.

This I what I have so far it renders the meta-fields.

```
    {% if product.metafields.custom.scents != blank %}
      <div class="product_scents">
          {% for p in product.metafields.custom.scents.value %}
              <div class="">{{ p }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>      
     {% endif %}
```

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: You cannot modify a product in the browser, you need an app.

Comment: if you want to capture more information for cart and checkout from the product page, you can use the [cart attributes](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/cart-use-cart-attributes-to-collect-more-information/td-p/613718)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research this is how I solved my problem I loop over the meta fields and the selected meta field gets added to the cart as a line item of the product.

```
    {% if product.metafields.custom.scents != blank %}
      <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-py-12 tw-space-y-4">
        <p>Select Your scent</p>
        {% for p in product.metafields.custom.scents.value %}
          <p class="line-item-property__field">
            <input type="radio" name="properties[Scent]" value="{{ p }}"> <span>{{ p }}</span><br>
          </p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```